# Copying images in Ubuntu 22.04 to project folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ubuntu

I am unable to copy images from my download folder to my project folder. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 lte in windows.

I have tried using the cp command and have had no success.

cp helvetica-neu.ttf c/users/------/portfolioapp/src/assets/images

Comment: [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)